# Can't Commit to repository using Versions (error code 210002)

Tags: svn, versions

I recently made some changes to my server setup that holds my repository. In doing these changes I changed my server's IP to a static IP (192.168.0.2). Apparently I need to regenerate a new known_hosts file at ~/.ssh/known_hosts which I have done. I am able to login via terminal to my server with ssh root@192.160.0.2/path/to/my/repo. The first time I did this after deleting (and backing up) my original know_hosts file I was notified that the fingerprint or something to that effect was out of line and that I chose to continue. This created a new host file and I thought I was in the clear. When I go to commit my changes to my repo using Versions I get the following error (as I did before swapping the known_hosts file)

```
Commit failed (details follow):
An unknown Subversion error occurred. (code = 210002)
```

Does anyone have experience with this issue after recreating the host file? Is there a way I can find a more verbose error message? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the RSA key on my computer. I ended up reverting the server's IP back to the original and voila. I was receiving SSLHandshake error 9806 but it appears to be working now.